# dynamic custom menu php

Tags: php, web

trying to get some thing like that dynamically

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Academics</a>
    <ul style="overflow: hidden; display: block; height: 0px; z-index: 51; opacity: 0.00980392;">
        <li><a href="bscs.php">Bs Computer Science</a></li>
        <li><a href="dit.php">Diplomas (DIT &amp; DCHE)</a></li>
        <li><a href="mbait.php">MBAIT</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class=" " href="#">College</a>
</ul>
```

the code is

```
<?php 
//========================================================
$result = mysql_query("    SELECT id, parentId, name
    FROM
        menu
    ORDER BY
        parentId, name");

$menuData = array(
    'items' => array(),
    'parents' => array()
);

while ($menuItem = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $menuData['items'][$menuItem['id']] = $menuItem;
    $menuData['parents'][$menuItem['parentId']][] = $menuItem['id'];
}

function buildMenu($parentId, $menuData)
{
    $html = '';

    if (isset($menuData['parents'][$parentId]))
    {
        $html = '<ul id="main_menu">';
        foreach ($menuData['parents'][$parentId] as $itemId)
        {
            $html .= '<li>' . $menuData['items'][$itemId]['name'];

                // find childitems recursively
                $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menuData);

            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    return $html;
}

// output the menu
echo buildMenu(0, $menuData); 
//=======================================================
 ?>
```

above code is showing only first parents elements in the menu and the remaing elements are not showing.. the menu is not working correctly becoz of the class id is not given in the ul tag.. and by writing this

```
echo '<ul id="main_menu">';
// output the menu
echo buildMenu(0, $menuData); 
echo "</ul>";
```

it shows nothing in the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this:

```
<?php

//========================================================
$result = mysql_query("    SELECT id, parentId, name, link
    FROM
        menu
    ORDER BY
        parentId, name");

$menuData = array(
    'items' => array(),
    'parents' => array()
);

while ($menuItem = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $menuData['items'][$menuItem['id']] = $menuItem;
    $menuData['parents'][$menuItem['parentId']][] = $menuItem['id'];
}

function buildMenu($parentId, $menuData)
{
    $html = '';

    if (isset($menuData['parents'][$parentId]) && count( $menuData['parents'][$parentId] ) > 0 ) {
       if( $parentId == "0" ){
          $html = '<ul id="main_menu">';
        }else{
          $html = '<ul id="sub_menu">';
        }
        foreach ($menuData['parents'][$parentId] as $itemId) {
            $html .= '<li>';
            $html .= strlen($menuData['items'][$itemId]['link']) > 2?
                     '<a href="'.$menuData['items'][$itemId]['link'].'">'.$menuData['items'][$itemId]['name'].'</a>':
                     $menuData['items'][$itemId]['name'];
            $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menuData);
            $html .= "</li>";
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
    } else {

        $html .= '<li>' . $menuData['items'][$parentId]['name'].'</li>';
    }

    return $html;
}

// output the menu
echo buildMenu(0, $menuData);
//=======================================================

?>
```

Comment: i got this error when try to run... This is good idea but the problem is that i got this error
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 15 bytes)

Comment: i got the error 

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 15 bytes)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the part were build childs was called again, resulting in a loop

Comment: Sorry again, Ill rewrite the code again to make it work, what I did in this answer does not work recursive.

Comment: thanks dear.. what about $itemId in this line.. its causing undefined  $html .= '<li>' . $menuData['items'][$itemId]['name'];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20460/discussion-between-natasha-and-john)

Comment: I rewrote it again. It should work now. Recursive items can be very confusing sometimes.

Comment: @John: You should also explain what the problem was and how you solved it. Not just placing code, otherwise the use is really too localized for this site.